# Find all customers who engaged continuously for 6 months

Tags: oracle, continuous

I need code help in Oracle

I have table with the following structure. This is an aggregate table grouped by `Account_ID` and `month` (month rolled to the start date of the month) and `number of transactions` performed in that month.

```
Account_ID Date      Trans_cnt
------------------------------
A00001     01Jan2018 12
A00002     01Jan2018 14
A00002     01Feb2018 01
A00003     01Feb2018 02
A00001     01Mar2018 12
```

I need to find accounts which have had continuous 6 months of transaction and 3 months of transactions

an example if account A00001 is analyzed for 6 months, then in a given year's time say from Jan 2018 to Dec 2018, this account should have continuous transactions from Jan to Jun or Feb to Jul; or Mar to Aug likewise.

Let me know how to come up with a sql for the same.

Comment: what did you try so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Does your table contain the date in form of string? Also, share the more data where you can validate it?

Comment: What do you exaxtly mean by **should have continuous transactions** ? Does customer should have transaction every day, quater, hour, month or maybe on or every second ?

Comment: Should have every month